# Move files on network to different locations via iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, windows, cocoa-touch, networking

I have files and directories setup on a Windows network share (\foo). I want to be able to move the files into different directories (eg. \foo\bar\baz.txt --> \foo\quux\baz.txt) via an iPhone app.

However, having failed to find a solution I think it might be a better idea to write a separate program that runs on the server that handles moving the files and have the iPhone app as a client that issues instructions to the server about what files to move.

Any suggestions on this would be much appreciated.

Edit: Since someone has voted to close this for not being clear... the question is: I want to move files on a network share from one directory to the other.

How do I do this using Objective-C/Cocoa Touch/iPhone SDK?

Comment: I would prefer to write it all as one app, but from what I've found moving the files from app the itself is somewhere between incredibly difficult to impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the file shares directly, you would have to implement an SMB client. I suppose you could pilfer code from Samba's [smbclient](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smbclient.1.html) and see if you can get it building on the iPhone.

A big advantage to using a web service is that you can set it up for access outside your LAN. This is much harder with SMB unless you already have a VPN set up.

An in-between possibility that just occurred to me is to expose the shares via WebDAV on IIS. In fact, this is probably much easier that writing your own service.